# IE restriction warning using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I want to run my application locally, all the images, styles, scripts are in the same directory, however IE gives resriction message despice the MOTW tag.

I have tried to put all the scripts in the same file - no result. Googled every corner of a web and still no results.

If the message would be one time only then no problem, however each time I open the application with IE it displayes the message and I am concerned about users, not myself. Asking user "Allow" the application to run each time is really not what I want.

I am using jQuery by the way.

What should I do? What are solutions for IE if I want my app to be running locally. 100% localy with no internet connection.

Comment: If you mean the `allow activex` message it's normal in IE, that's how annoying IE is. The only thing YOU can do is lower the security slider in IE's options. Users might have a different security level. By default it should cache the answer so next time they visit it won't show up.

Comment: Are you using a local web server or just trying to access the filesystem directly through IE?

Comment: Normal functionality unfortunately. If it's just running locally, then you could try to change the users IE security settings. Try clicking `Tools > Internet Options > Security > Internet > Custom Level` , and it's probably one of the options to do with `active scripting`. Try playing around with those options, they should disable the popup from appearing every-time you run the application. Fine if your running it locally and your the only user, but not really scalable.

Comment: Thanks for the input, however I mentioned that I want somehow not to have the restriction warning. Asking user to change security options is out of the question